# Perl: V 5.8.8 : Can't locate auto/XML/LibXSLT/new.al on CentOS5/RHEL5

Tags: xml, perl, centos5, rhel5

I am getting 
Can't locate auto/XML/LibXSLT/new.al
error on my CentOS5 machine installed Perl 5.8.8

This issue is related with libxml2 and perl modules `XML::LibXML, XML::LibXSLT`.
For both version in 1.70.

Upon settling both modules, further I am getting error for

```
Can't locate auto/XML/LibXSLT/new.al
```

which seems to be a autoload function of `LibXSLT`, But surprisingly I am not finding any file as `new.al`.

Here is the code snippet through which I am getting this error

```
use XML::LibXML;
use XML::LibXSLT;
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new;
my $xslt = XML::LibXSLT->new;
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's a symptom of a bad install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `XML::LibXSLT` installation is not healthy. Try below. It worked for me:

```
# yum -y install perl-XML-LibXSLT
# perl -e 'use XML::LibXSLT'
```

And it worked for me on ubuntu as well. Here is the command:

```
# aptitude install libxml-libxslt-perl
```

Comment: No, Actually it is offering libxslt-1.63, from el5 repo, but I need version 1.70, as my libXML is 1.70 and strictly bonded to use these version only for our application. I have installed v1.70 from source but some how it is not taking that through apache..else I am trying to run that code through system it is working fine..means when request coming from web apache not taking version XSLT 1.70 but through system its working. :(

Comment: @Yogi How did you install? Using `perl Makefile.PL && make all test && sudo make install`?

Comment: Your test would not generate the error even if you did suffer from it because it only happens when `XML::LibXSLT->new` is executed. Why didn't you run the code he posted?!