# Check which core loadable modules are being used by Perl through apache?

Tags: xml, linux, perl, xslt

I am getting Apache error saying

```
Error in Perl code: 

Can't locate loadable object for module XML::LibXSLT
```

Is there any way I can figure out exactly which loadable module is missing? As per the above error it is looking for some missing module, and I have  installed all needed modules.

Comment: THis is a screwed up installation of `XML::LibXSLT` which you have been following up on StackOverflow for a long time. You have to get the installation right, Else you will continue to face unknown problems.

Comment: You asked exactly this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283898) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20258993). What is wrong with the answers you got then? I am not especially pleased to have wasted my time writing pretty much the same answer as you have already been given.

Comment: @Borodin I have tried methods mentioned on another  links, Indeed those were correct methods to fix these things, I have tried and verified from those ends, That is why I am here with new questions to fix errors. Those solutions are not working. Let me take a look in to DynaLoader part which you just mentioned. Thanks a lot for providing this look around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you install [`XML::LibXSLT`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXSLT)? At a guess, you copied its files into place on the Apache installation. You *must* run the installation procedure, otherwise your module won't work properly.

Your question is *nothing* to do with *core* modules, or modules at all come to that.

The error message is

```
Can't locate loadable object for module ...
```

tells you that a *loadable object* can't be found, and that is very different from a Perl module.

This is an error from the [`DynaLoader`](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/perl5.004_04/ext/DynaLoader/DynaLoader.pm) module, which is used to load *shared object* or *DLL* files that the Perl part of a module relies on. In this case `XML::LibXSLT` is looking for the XS code that allows it to call the Gnome libxslt library.

The XS code is part of the module and distributed with it. The installation procedure preprocesses, compiles and links it and puts it in the correct place on your system. Your error message shows that this hasn't been done.

Comment: Thanks for above update, I am looking into it, Is there any way to verify what DynLoader is exactly configured with, as we have some std tool like "xml2-config" for "libxml2" and "xslt-config" for libxslt.